# Setting conditions on number of Tap gesture in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `UILabel` and when i double tap on it ,it should assign value of Label to the other view's `UITextView` otherwise next view's textview should be empty.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
[tapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[tapRecognizer setDelegate:self];

[holderView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];

tapRecognizer = nil;

UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(LaunchText)];
[doubleTapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
[doubleTapRecognizer setDelegate:self];


[holderView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapRecognizer];
holderView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

[tapRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTapRecognizer];


/*n=[SingleTon getInstance];
n.Name=textLabel.text;*/

if (doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired==2) {
     n.Name=@"hi";
}
/* if (doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired==2) {
      n.Name=textLabel.text;
}*/
else{
//n.Name=textLabel.text;
      n.Name=@"hellow";
}

 -(void) LaunchText
 {
      [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"textAdd" sender:self];
 }
```

I am always getting if condition, else part never runs, What is the issue with my code?

Comment: These n.Name value are for testing.

Answer (score 0):

`doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired==2` is the value you set to how many times the user has to tap to set off the gesture recognizer. it you want to allow for single and double taps you can keep a count on the gesture recognizer target and see how many times they've tapped over a giving time, like 0.2 secs or whatever time you want. I'm not 100% sure but you could also try to add two gestures to the label one for `numberOfTapsRequired = 1` and `numberOfTapsRequired = 2` and have them both perform different functions. Again i'm not sure on the two recognizers but you could give it a try and try the other method otherwise.

Comment: There is nothing like 'numberofTaps'

Comment: But I have already done that. You can see different code for different number of taps. My issue is in if condition.

Comment: and the if statement is always called because of this: doubleTapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:2

Comment: My issue is my else condition never runs it always displays what is written in if condition

Comment: this: if (doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired==2) {
     n.Name=@"hi";
} is always called because of this line: [doubleTapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code.

```
//first add single tap
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleT:)];
[tapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[holderView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];

//now add double tap
 UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleT:)];
 [doubleTapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
 [holderView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapRecognizer];

 holderView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

 [tapRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTapRecognizer];
```

Now Implement Single Tap and Double Tap Method

```
-(void)singleT:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gest
{
    NSLog(@"Single");
}
-(void)doubleT:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gest
{
    NSLog(@"double");
}
```

Maybe this will help you.

Comment: I cannot do like this because my holderview is created programmatically if I create functions like you said then I have no access of holderView in these functions